# how to switch axis in agendaweek in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

i need to switch axis in fullcalendar agendaweek view, and make the hours in the header and the days in the rows i've been going trough the code but couldn't find from where to start, is there a way to make custom views in fullcalendar ? can anybody help with this ?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this..I too need this very badly..please help...@zerzer